# Laravel get relation count where a field in the database is set to a certain value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

I have a Task model and a Step model. Each Task can have multiple steps. I want to be able to display all tasks including a progress bar. The length of the progress bar will be calculated by the total steps and the total steps that are completed. So I will do a calculation like:

```
100% / $total_steps * $total_steps_completed
```

A step that has been completed has it's status in the database set to 1. I know how to get the $total_steps. I just do a count($task->steps) so it counts the total rows in the array.

But how can I count the steps that have a status of 1?

Task Model:

```
class Task
{
    public function steps()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Step');
    }
}
```

Step Model:

```
class Step
{
    public function task()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
    }
}
```

TasksController:

```
class TasksController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tasks = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->tasks->with('steps')->get();

        return view('tasks', compact('tasks');
    }
}
```

Each Task belongs to a user, hence the `User::find()->tasks` etc..

In my `steps` table I have the following field:

```
$table->integer('status');
```

This can be set to either 0 or 1. In my Tasks -> `index.blade.php` view I have a simple foreach:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    {!! $task->id !!} // This is 1 for example

    Total Steps: {!! count($task->steps) !!} // Returns 5 if there are 5 rows in the steps database with task_id `1` for example

@endforeach
```

Now, what I need, is to count the total steps that have it's status set to `1`, so I can perform my calculation and display the progress bar. I think I should add a function for this, or maybe a scope, in my steps model. But I am stuck with this, so any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a relation with condition to return all completed steps for a task:

**Task**

```
public function completedSteps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Step')->where('status','=', 1);;
}
```

Then you can get your tasks along with steps and completed steps:

**TasksController**

```
$tasks = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->tasks->with('steps', 'completed_steps')->get();
```

and in your view you can access the `steps` and in the same time count the `completed_steps` :

**View**

```
count( $task->completedSteps()->get() );
```

Comment: You cannot apply scope to a collection.

Comment: @OzanKurt : to which scope are you referring to ?

Comment: I was thinking this way yesterday but I couldn't wrap my head around it yet, but it's indeed very simple and exactly what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "scope" laravel feature.
You can find some informations about it here

http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2015/06/23/using-scopes-with-laravel-5/

You'd basically have this method on your Step model:

```
class Step extends Model
{
    public function scopeDone($query)
    {
        return $query->where('status', 1);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to get the steps done by:

```
Total Steps: {{ $task->steps()->done()->count() }}
```

Note: In order to use scopes, it's important to get your steps as a relationship (by adding the double brackets). Otherwise you would get a simple collection with no scope capabilities.

Comment: You cannot apply scope to a collection.

Comment: @OzanKurt I've edited my answer. If you treat the steps as a relationship (by adding the double bracket) you can apply it. You can see it at the bottom of the article I linked.

Comment: Nice answer then... As you mentioned if you don't use double braces that is not a relation object any more. ;)

Comment: This is probably the "better" / "cleaner" way to do it, for me personally at least. Although both answers this and the accepted one) would do it. I might try them both and see which fits better for me :)